# How to generate components in a specific folder with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am using Angular 4 with Angular CLI and I am able to create a new component with the following command.

```
E:\HiddenWords>ng generate component plainsight
```

But I need to generate a child component inside plainsight. Is there a way to do it with Angular CLI?

Comment: ng generate component your/path/from/the/app/folder/plainsight

Comment: as @Maxime mentioned, or cd into the directory

Comment: To have a nice result when you first run something like: `ng generate component plainsight` as a parent and now you want to generate a child then just run: `ng generate component plainsight/child`

Comment: A handy tool I use is -d at the end of the command, which will do a dry run i.e. not actually add the files to your project, only show you where they would go. That way you can check that they are going into the desired folder:

```ng generate component path/to/folder/plainsight -d```

Answer (score 295):

The `ng g component plainsight/some-name` makes a **new directory** when we use it.

The final output will be:

```
plainsight/some-name/some-name.component.ts
```

To avoid that, make use of the [flat option](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component) `ng g component plainsight/some-name --flat`  and it will generate the files **without** making a new folder

```
plainsight/some-name.component.ts
```

Comment: the --flat option is what I was looking for!

Comment: @user3611927  --flat is the answer as will use existing folders and only make folders that dont exist.  Perfect!!  This should be the default behavious IMHO

Comment: `--flat` is actually enabled by default, so there's no need to explicitly type it. If we want the generated file(s) to be placed inside a folder, generate with `--flat false`.

Answer (score 171):

There are couple of methods to create component in a specific directory.

### Method 1: "Open in Integrated Terminal" - Quick, Simple and Error free method

i.e. You want to create a component in a `app/common` folder as shown in the image given below, then follow these steps

1. Right click on the folder in which you want to create component.
2. Select option `Open in Integrated Terminal` or `Open in Command Prompt`.
3. In new terminal (you'll see your selected path), then type `ng g c my-component`

Also you can check this process through this image
[image]

### Method 2: "Copy Relative Path" and Paste on Terminal

1. Right click on folder in which you want to create component
2. From context menu, select `Copy Relative Path`
3. On termincal, type `cd`, press <kbd>space</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste the copied path and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. You will see that directory has been changed.

Also you can check this process through this image
[image]

### Method 3: Type complete path on terminal

i.e. You want to create `component` in some folder, you type the whole command including path and component name.

```
ng g c relative-path/my-component
```

Also you can check this process through this image
[image]

**Note (method-3):** angular will not allow you to create component outside app folder so for component, your base path will be `app` folder that's why in my case I had to start with `auth/a-component` instead of `src/app/auth/a-component`

Comment: This will open up in a new terminal

Comment: Methods 1 and 2 are ignoring my working directory and creating it in the root

Comment: @xr280xr Its impossible. They should work. You must have making some mistake.

Answer (score 35):

`ng g c component-name`

For specify custom location: `ng g c specific-folder/component-name`

here `component-name` will be created inside specific-folder.

Similarl approach can be used for generating other components like `directive`, `pipe`, `service`, `class`, `guard`, `interface`, `enum`, `module`, etc.

Answer (score 20):

more shorter code to generate component: `ng g c component-name` 
to specify its location: `ng g c specific-folder/component-name`

Additional info 
more shorter code to generate directive: `ng g d directive-name` 
to specify its location: `ng g d specific-folder/directive-name`

Answer (score 14):

The above options were not working for me because unlike creating a directory or file in the terminal, when the CLI generates a component, it adds the path **src/app** by default to the path you enter.

If I generate the component from my main app folder like so (WRONG WAY)

```
ng g c ./src/app/child/grandchild
```

the component that was generated was this:

```
src/app/src/app/child/grandchild.component.ts
```

so I only had to type

```
ng g c child/grandchild
```

Hopefully this helps someone

Answer (score 11):

Use 'ng generate component ./target_directory/Component_Name'

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

**It Super Easy,**

[image]

Other way,

in terminal go your FOLDER,

****xxx\FOLDER_NAME>cd FOLDER_NAME**

**xxx\FOLDER_NAME> ng generate component plainsight**

Bonus point if you lasy like me to copy path(Visual studio code),

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Create a component inside a specific folder:

```
ng g c folder-name/component-name
```

Create a component inside a folder for a  specific (existing) module with Angular-CLI:

```
ng g c folder-name/component-name --module=folder-name/moduleName.module.ts
```

Comment: We can use - ng g c modules/moduleName/IfComponentsFolder/ComponentYouWantToCreate --project parentProjectName

Answer (score 6):

```
ng g c folderName/SubFolder/.../componentName --spec=false
```

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't having any luck with the above answers (including `--flat`), but what worked for me was:

```
cd path/to/specific/directory
```

From there, I ran the `ng g c mynewcomponent`

Answer (score 5):

To open a terminal in VS code just type `CTRL` + `~` which will open the terminal. Here are the steps:

1. Check for the particular component where you need to generate the new component.
2. Redirect the path to the particular folder/component where you need to generate another component

FOR EXAMPLE: `cd src/app/particularComponent`

In the place of **particularComponent**, type the component name in which you need to generate the new component.

3. Once you are in the component where you need to generate the new component, just type this command: `ng g c NewComponentName`

(Change the name **NewComponentName** to your required component name.)

Answer (score 5):

### 2021 Further speed up using IDE pluggins

If you want to further speed up this usual process and avoid common mistakes which cost you time you can try with visual studio code plugins.

For example I use [Angular-Schematics](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cyrilletuzi.angular-schematics) and I avoid the terminal. You can invoke the ng cli with your mouse selections.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Angular CLI provides all the commands you need in your app development. For your specific requirement, you can easily use `ng g` (`ng generate`) to get the work done.

`ng g c directory/component-name` will generate `component-name` component in the `directory` folder.

Following is a map of a few simple commands you can use in your application.

1. `ng g c comp-name` or `ng generate component comp-name` to create a component with the name 'comp-name'
2. `ng g s serv-name` or `ng generate service serv-name` to create a service with the name 'serv-name'
3. `ng g m mod-name` or `ng generate module mod-name` to create a module with the name 'mod-name'
4. `ng g m mod-name --routing` or `ng generate module mod-name --routing` to create a module with the name 'mod-name' with angular routing

Hope this helps!

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

**Need for using --dryRun when using custom directory**

You can pass your custom directory path along with `ng` command.

`ng g c myfolder\mycomponent`

But there are chances that you miss spell the path and either new folder gets created or target directory changes. For this reason `dryRun` is very helpful. It displays an output of how the changes is going to be affected.
[image]

After verifying the result you can run the same command without `-d` to make the changes.

> --dryRun=true|false
>
> When true, runs through and reports activity without writing out results.
>
> Default: false
>
> Aliases: -d

Official Doc :- https://angular.io/cli/generate

Answer (score 2):

Open the specific folder Terminal use this command

ng g c component name --flat

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window and navigate to the root of your Angular project. create a folder

Run the following command to generate a new component in a specific folder:

```
ng generate component <folderName>/<componentName>
```

For example, if you want to create a new component called "myComponent" in a folder called "components", the command would be:

```
ng generate component components/myComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
ng g component plainsight/some-name
```

It will create "plainsight" folder and generate some-name component inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
ng g component plainsight/some-name.component.ts
```

Or try it manually, if you feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project folder in command prompt or in Project Terminal.

Run cmd :    ng g c componentname

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the directory of your project.
use `cd path/to/directory` then use `ng g c component_name` it automates everything and is error free

the `g c` means generate component

Comment: I get following error with Angular 9

"Unknown option: '--spec'"

Comment: dont ignore spec files.. Tests are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

### Firstly to create a Component you need to use:-

- ng g c componentname

  *By using above command New Component will be created in a folder with

  (componentname) you specified above.*

### But if you need to create a component inside of another component or in specific folder:-

- ng g c componentname/newComponentName

Answer (score 0):

If you use VSCode, consider using the [Angular Console](https://angularconsole.com/)

It provides an interface for the Angular CLI. You will see an option to specify the path.

> The Angular CLI is immensely powerful and extensible. In fact, there are so many capabilities that it is helpful for developers to have all of the different configuration options for every command available to them.
>
> With Angular Console, you’ll get recommendations and be able to pull up even the most easily forgotten or rarely used features!
>
> Angular Console is, first and foremost, a more productive way to work with what the Angular CLI provides.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to create a component `Container` in a module `Box`, and module is already created and is present in it its own folder `src/app/box`.

You can do this - when asked for component name, provide path to component and component name.

```
ng g c -m box
? What name would you like to use for the component? box/Container
CREATE src/app/box/container/container.component.scss (0 bytes)
CREATE src/app/box/container/container.component.html (24 bytes)
CREATE src/app/box/container/container.component.spec.ts (647 bytes)
CREATE src/app/box/container/container.component.ts (288 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/box/box.module.ts (286 bytes)
```