# angular cli 1.4+ - create component in an inner module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have the following structure:

```
-AppModule
  --AdminModule
    ---HomepageModule
```

How I can create a component HomepageModule Component?

I tried:

```
ng g c admin/homepage/my-new-component
ng g c admin/homepage/my-new-component --module homepage
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closes
t module.
More than one module matches. Use skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest modul
e.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate components in specific folder with angular-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851399/how-to-generate-components-in-specific-folder-with-angular-cli)

Comment: Did you look at what I tried? because it's same

Comment: you can go to the folder of the module ,then run you command `ng g c my-new-component` , it will be created in the module

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says, It's because you have more than one module

You can solve it by specifying the name of the module you want to import the component to it.

for example

```
    ng generate component componentName --module=app.module
```

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component)