# Preconfigure a default folder for Angular Component Generation (ng g c) and omit folder name in ng command

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v7

Is there any way to specify a default folder name in a configuration file like `angular.json`, so that all developers running the cli-command `ng g c MyComponent --skipTests` without folder name will create components in this preconfigured folder (e.g. `MyFolder`) by default?

**This query holds the knowledge of** [How to generate components in a specific folder with angular-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851399/how-to-generate-components-in-a-specific-folder-with-angular-cli)

It is not a duplicate because the above question only answers how to specify the target folder in the command line call, and not **how to preconfigure a default folder**.

Suppose there are several developers, and all create a lot of components that should all be placed in one specific folder.

Instead of typing the folder every time in the commandline call, angular should use a default even if no folder is specified during the commandline call. That way, the developers do not need to remember to provide the `MyFolder` name all the time.

For example

```
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent1 --skipTests
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent2 --skipTests
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent3 --skipTests
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent4 --skipTests
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent5 --skipTests
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent6 --skipTests
ng g c MyFolder/MyComponent7 --skipTests
```

they should just be allowed to type:

```
ng g c MyComponent1 --skipTests
ng g c MyComponent2 --skipTests
ng g c MyComponent3 --skipTests
ng g c MyComponent4 --skipTests
ng g c MyComponent5 --skipTests
ng g c MyComponent6 --skipTests
ng g c MyComponent7 --skipTests
```

**but the components should still be generated in `MyFolder` folder.**

Comment: I dont know why marked this query as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851399/how-to-generate-components-in-a-specific-folder-with-angular-cli, though its not.

Comment: Thanks @Risadinha for making the best edit.

Comment: If you are using webpack, maybe this helps: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471

Comment: For now I am not using Webpack, well thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try.